# How do you get the most recent posts from a given user on Facebook graph?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the last posts of the friends of a given user (php)
    $Fb = new Facebook(array('appId'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx','secret'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'));
    $access_token = $Fb->getAccessToken();
    // I get a token
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$id."/posts?access_token=".$access_token;
    $data = file_get_contents($url); // works with any other command.
    $var = json_decode($data, true); // as an array, not object
    $txt .= display_tree($var); // my own way to display
No result.

Comment: Are you trying to get the latest posts from a specific user who is a friend of your authenticated user, or hte latest posts from your authenticated user.

Comment: do `var_dump($data);` and post the output.

Answer (score 1):

- Use the Facebook PHP SDK to get authorization from the user, and use the "scope" method to get the "read_stream" permission, that will make it possible to see the users profile stream, more known as "wall", but, as you wan't to see there friends updates as well, you can ask for the "offline_access" permission, then, after the user has logged into facebook, the site will return data to you, with the users wall posts and there home posts ( the home posts contain the data that there are subscribed to, so there will be friends posts and other pages posts).

Then, once you have the permission "offline_access", you can get that data at any time, using the users Access Token, given from that permission.

This file, checks if the user is online in Facebook, if not, they will be taken to the facebook login page AND, if the user did not give the permission yet, they will be asked for that. The "scope" after the loginURL is where you will put the permissions wanted.

---

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php'; // Make sure to have the Facebook PHP SDK

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'APPID',
  'secret' => 'APPSECRET',
));
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

/* We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
   If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
   Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
   token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook. */

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    // These are the graph calls -->

    $dt = $facebook->api('/me');
    $lk = $facebook->api('/me/likes');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Handler for Login Status
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => "email,user_birthday,user_likes,user_location,offline_access,read_stream"));
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
?>

<?php if (!$user): header ('Location:'.$loginUrl.''); //checks if the user is logged in
else: 
        // Do Something here. This next bit of code shows what comes out of those calls.
      echo "<pre>"; 
      print_r($dt);
      echo"</pre>";

      echo"<br/><br/>";

      echo "<pre>"; 
      print_r($lk);
      echo"</pre>";
endif
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it in Facebook's graph explorer tool first so you isolate the problem away from any problems in your php code.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Just looking at your code, it looks like you haven't asked for read_stream permissions? Just an access token alone will only get you public posts and perhaps the user in question has no public posts.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Answer (score 0):

There's probably an error which Facebook gives out, which you can't read cause you can't by default read error-pages.

`file_get_contents()` needs to have a given stream_context (third parameter) which says `'ignore_error' => TRUE`

Else you can't see what kind of error Facebook gives you as a json, and the function will only return FALSE instead.

[stream_context_create()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php)